# The equality condition of Jensen's inequality in derivation of variational sparse gaussian process

Tags: gaussian-process

I am trying to understand the derivation of [Variational Learning of Inducing Variables in Sparse Gaussian Processes](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v5/titsias09a/titsias09a.pdf) and how Eq 8:

$$
F_V(X_m, \phi)=\int p(f|f_m)\phi(f_m)\log \frac{p(y|f)p(f_m)}{\phi(f_m)}dfdf_m
$$

can be "maximized" to Eq 9:

$$
F_V(X_m) = \log[N(y|0,\sigma^2I+Q_{nn})]-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}Tr(\tilde{K})
$$

The paper said that the detail can be found in the technical report ([Variational Model Selection for Sparse Gaussian Process Regression](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9525/98cd5672d79c0eda370a21dd7a39c7da6d43.pdf)), in that I found following steps in page 14:

- Merge the logs

$$
F_V(X_m, \phi(f_m))=\int_{f_m}\phi(f_m){\log \frac{G(f_m,y)p(f_m)}{\phi(f_m)}}df_m
$$

- Reverse Jensen's inequality to maximize wrt $\phi(f_m)$:

$$
F_V(X_m) = \log \int_{f_m} G(f_m, y) p(f_m) df_m
$$

While I can try to fill the gap by:

$$
\begin{align*}
F_V(X_m,\phi(f_m)) &= E_{f_m\sim\phi(f_m)} \log \frac{G(f_m,y)p(f_m)}{\phi(f_m)} \\
&\le \log E_{f_m\sim\phi(f_m)}\frac{G(f_m,y)p(f_m)}{\phi(f_m)} \\
&= \log \int_{f_m} \phi(f_m)\frac{G(f_m,y)p(f_m)}{\phi(f_m)} \\
&= \log \int_{f_m} G(f_m,y) p(f_m)df_m
\end{align*}
$$

However, I can't see how the equality can holds here (like the derivation of EM algorithm?). It's obvious that $\log$ is not linear and $\frac{G(f_m,y)p(f_m)}{\phi(f_m)}$ is not constant and $\phi(f_m)$ is not a "delta distribution". Does Titsias just maximize an "upper bound" which is not ensured to increase like in Bayesian Optimization?